# fill a select box with a selection of options from another select box

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

On page 2 of a php-form I have a dynamically created select box filled with content from a database (BOX1). This is already a selection based on page one of a php-form.
There is also an empty select box (BOX2).

Now I want users to be able to "transfer" items from BOX1 to BOX2 by clicking a button. This page of the form should therefor contain these steps:

1. they select **one** or **several** items from **BOX1**
2. they **click** the move-button
3. the items **disappear** from BOX1 and **appear** in BOX2
4. rinse and repeat until they are satisfied with their selection
5. click the "**finish**"-**button** and move forward to page 3

How should I go about this?

I was thinking to use php-self with each click, but that seems unwieldy.

Edit: I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3530784/958903) on a different question which should help me along.

Comment: Sounds a lot like something you should be doing in javascript.

Comment: Yes, and I was hoping to avoid that... but, looking about, it seems indeed so.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using below jQuery code, change the below code based on your requirements, here

```
$(function() {
    $("#box1").click(function() {
        var clkVal = $("#box1 option:selected").val();
        var clkTxt = $("#box1 option:selected").text();
        $("#box1 option:selected").remove();
        $("#box2").append('<option value="'+ clkVal +'">'+ clkTxt +'</option>');
    });

    $("#box2").click(function() {
        var clkVal = $("#box2 option:selected").val();
        var clkTxt = $("#box2 option:selected").text();
        $("#box2 option:selected").remove();
        $("#box1").append('<option value="'+ clkVal +'">'+ clkTxt +'</option>');
    });
});
```

if you are new to jquery, please download latest jquery library and include in your header and #box1 referring to id of your box1 select box you can just replace box1 by your original id.

I hope this will help you.